# QGis SQL Query - "Deleting almost duplicates entries"

Tags: sql, qgis

I have a table with a distance matrix between all the points of an other table. On the distance matrix, I just kept the lignes with a distance less than 100m.
I call the points placed less than 100 m away from eachother duplicates entries. But on the distance matrix, each duplicates entry takes 2 lines
The distance matrix presents like this :

```
InputID TargetID Distance

   1       2       75

   1       3       35

   2       1       75

   3       1       35
```

I’d like to keep just one of those duplicates entry, which means that on the previous exemple I’d like to keep only the ligne of the 1, because the 2 and the 3 are placed less than 100m away of the 1. But if I only keep the 1 on the distance matrix, I also need to keep only the 1 on my original table.

I use the SQL Query tool of QGis but I don’t really know how to program. Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some subquery in join for retrive the value to delete

```
delete from my_table  m2
inner join (
  select m.distance, min(m.InputId) min_id
  from my_table  m.
  inner join (
    select distance, count(*)
    from my_table 
    group by Distance 
    having count(*) > 1 
  ) t on t.distance  = m.distance
  group by distance 
) t2 on t2.distance = m2.distance and t2.min_id  = m2.InputId
```

Comment: In this code, my_table is the table of the distance matrix ? m.InputID is the attribute InputID of my_table ? But where is the original table from which I calculated the distance matrix ?

Comment: i have assumed  that your result is a table  .that i named  my_table  (a matrix is very similar to a table  )  . otherwise  ..show a correct data sample  with table and column name  and coherent values  .. .. .i can't image how you have stored  your datas..

Comment: Here is my original table : 
[Originale table][2]
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igCWy.png
 In this table, the ID of the lines is "Ref"
And here is my matrix table. In this table, I just kept the "almost duplicates entries" by kepting only the lignes with "Nom_latin"="Nom_latin2" AND "Distance" < 100m. So this table only shows the "duplicate entries" and I'd like to keep only one of the duplicates in the original table. In the table, the ID are InputID and TargetID and correspond to the "Ref" of the duplicates lines.
[Distance matrix][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLXh3.png